# disable user selection in qlistwidget

Tags: pyqt4, qlistwidget

I have an ordinary qlistwidget in pyqt4. I sometimes want to prevent the user from making a selection, but still want to set the selection programmatically. So setting the selection mode to noselection won't work. Is there a way in which I can prevent the user from making a selection?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Disable the list widget? (`lw.setEnabled(False)`)

Answer (score 0):

I would install an event filter on the widget to catch and discard mouse events.